# std::bind syntax difference between global and member functions

Tags: c++, c++11

When using `std::bind`, why is it that I must specify a `&` before a member function, but not before a global function?  For instance, my main.cpp is:

```
  1 #include <functional>
  2 
  3 class Foo
  4 {
  5   public:
  6     void Exec(void) {}
  7 };
  8 
  9 void Exec(void) {}
 10 
 11 int main(void)
 12 {
 13   Foo inst;
 14   auto blah1 = std::bind(Exec);
 15   //auto blah2 = std::bind(Foo::Exec, &inst);
 16   auto blah2 = std::bind(&Foo::Exec, &inst);
 17   blah1();
 18   blah2();
 19   return 0;
 20 }
```

This compiles fine, but if I uncomment 15 and comment line 16, I get:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o a.out -std=c++11 -Wall
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:31: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Foo::Exec()’
   auto blah2 = std::bind(Foo::Exec, &inst);
```

I really don't understand this error.  I would have expected both instances to either require `&` or not, but they turned out to be treated differently.  Can someone help me understand why the compiler is picky about this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member functions require the `&` explicitly in order to form a pointer. This is an intentional design that pre-dates `std::bind` and is supposed to reduce programmer error. For example this code:

```
Foo;
```

will cause an error if `Foo` is a member function, but it is valid code if `Foo` is a free function. Probably the person intended to call the function and forgot the parentheses.  Obviously, we could concoct more complicated examples.

It's too late to go back and require `&` for non-member functions though, too much existing code relies on the "decay" to function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `&` on a "normal" function, you get a pointer to function.

If you don't use it and pass it to `std::bind`, you are actually passing a reference to function; internally it's decayed to a pointer to function and stored as such.

There's no "reference to member function", only "pointer to member function", so you have to use the `&` operator. The standard, in fact, allows using the name of a non-static member function only 1) in a class-member access expression and 2) to form a pointer to member with `&`.

Comment: Why isn't there a "reference to member function"?  Are they not implemented the same way internally like `void Exec(void)` and `void Foo_Exec(Foo*)` (or whatever name mangling happens from gcc)?