where memory will be allocated to global function and address of global function will change at runtime or not in c++?
// bind example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::bind

// a function: (also works with function object: std::divides<double> my_divide;)
double my_divide (double x, double y) {return x/y;}

struct MyPair {
  double a,b;
  double multiply() {return a*b;}
};

int main () {
  using namespace std::placeholders;    // adds visibility of _1, _2, _3,...

  // binding functions:
  auto fn_five = std::bind (&my_divide,10,2);               // returns 10/2
  std::cout << fn_five() << '\n';                          // 5

  MyPair ten_two {10,2};

  // binding members:
  auto bound_member_fn = std::bind (&MyPair::multiply,_1); // returns x.multiply()
  std::cout << bound_member_fn(ten_two) << '\n';           // 20

  return 0;
}

passing address of global function my_divide to std::bind is valid or not?
from where memory is allocated for my_divide global function on heap or stack or BSS segment and does address of global function is will change at runtime or not?

See this picture: code will be stored at fixed addresses in memory region for code, this part won't change during runtime. Your usage of bind is fine, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293653/stdbind-syntax-difference-between-global-and-member-functions

In C++, "the heap" is an imprecise term for memory that's returned by new (usually) or malloc (for legacy C behavior). It's imprecise for multiple reasons, one reason being the idea that there's only one heap ("THE" heap). Similarly, "the stack" is imprecise. It's used for function-local variables, even if the CPU doesn't actually store those on the CPU stack.
But these are two types of dynamic memory, with variable lifetimes. Functions live forever and do not move (pointers do not change). That's also the case for every C++ object that lives forever. So you can't figure out where the memory came from, and you don't need to care because you don't need to return that memory.

when std::bad_function_call exception will raise while binding global function to std::bind.

I suppose the question is when std::bad_function_call will be thrown when binding a non-member function using std::bind. The answer is simple, std::bind itself won't. Any exception could occur when binding/forwarding an argument with class type, but your argument has type double. That's not a class.
